# Stratigraphic column in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

My goal is to create a stratigraphic column (colored stacked rectangles) using matplotlib like the example below.
[image]

Data is in this format:

```
depth = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] #depth (feet) below ground surface    
lithotype = [4,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6,2] #lithology type. 4 = clay, 6 = sand, 2 = silt
```

I tried matplotlib.patches.Rectangle but it's cumbersome. Wondering if someone has another suggestion.

Comment: I'd suggest using a [`barh` plot](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.barh.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.barh) and playing the height and width of the bars.

Comment: FYI, I wrote a package to make plots like this: [`striplog`](https://code.agilescientific.com/striplog/). I ended up using patches... it's easier but slower than `fill_between`. I'll make you an answer using `striplog` and you can at least compare your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Imho using `Rectangle` is not so difficult nor cumbersome.

[image]

```
from numpy import ones
from matplotlib.pyplot import show, subplots
from matplotlib.cm import get_cmap
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle as r

# a simplification is to use, for the lithology types, a qualitative colormap
# here I use Paired, but other qualitative colormaps are displayed in
# https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html#qualitative

qcm = get_cmap('Paired')

# the data, augmented with type descriptions
# note that depths start from zero
depth = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] # depth (feet) below ground surface    
lithotype = [4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 1, 6, 2] # lithology type.
types = {1:'swiss cheese', 2:'silt', 4:'clay', 5:'silty sand', 6:'sand'}

# prepare the figure
fig, ax = subplots(figsize = (4, 8))
w = 2 # a conventional width, used to size the x-axis and the rectangles
ax.set(xlim=(0,2), xticks=[]) # size the x-axis, no x ticks
ax.set_ylim(ymin=0, ymax=depth[-1])
ax.invert_yaxis()
fig.suptitle('Soil Behaviour Type')
fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.5)

# plot a series of dots, that eventually will be covered by the Rectangle\s
# so that we can draw a legend
for lt in set(lithotype):
    ax.scatter(lt, depth[1], color=qcm(lt), label=types[lt], zorder=0)
fig.legend(loc='center right')
ax.plot((1,1), (0,depth[-1]), lw=0)

# do the rectangles
for d0, d1, lt in zip(depth, depth[1:], lithotype):
    ax.add_patch(
        r( (0, d0), # coordinates of upper left corner
          2, d1-d0, # conventional width on x, thickness of the layer
          facecolor=qcm(lt), edgecolor='k'))

# That's all, folks!
show()
```

As you can see, placing the rectangles is not complicated, what is indeed cumbersome is to properly prepare the `Figure` and the `Axes`.

I know that I omitted part of the qualifying details from my solution, but I hope these omissions won't stop you from profiting from my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**I made a package called [`striplog`](https://code.agilescientific.com/striplog/index.html) for handling this sort of data and making these kinds of plots.**

The tool can read CSV, LAS, and other formats directly (if the format is rather particular), but we can also construct a `Striplog` object manually. First let's set up the basic data:

```py
depth = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]    
lithotype = [4,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6,2]
KEY = {2: 'silt', 4: 'clay', 5: 'mud', 6: 'sand'}
```

Now you need to know that a `Striplog` is composed of `Interval` objects, each of which can have one or more `Component` elements:

```py
from striplog import Striplog, Component, Interval

intervals = []
for top, base, lith in zip(depth, depth[1:], lithotype):
    comp = Component({'lithology': KEY[lith]})
    iv = Interval(top, base, components=[comp])
    intervals.append(iv)
    
s = Striplog(intervals).merge_neighbours()  # Merge like with like.
```

This results in `Striplog(3 Intervals, start=1.0, stop=10.0)`. Now we'd like to make a plot using an appropriate `Legend` object.

```py
from striplog import Legend

legend_csv = u"""colour, width, component lithology
#F7E9A6, 3, Sand
#A68374, 2.5, Silt
#99994A, 2, Mud
#666666, 1, Clay"""

legend = Legend.from_csv(text=legend_csv)

s.plot(legend=legend, aspect=2, label='lithology')
```

Which gives:

[image: The result of plotting our striplog]

Admittedly the plotting is a little limited, but it's just `matplotlib` so you can always add more code. To be honest, if I were to build this tool today, I think I'd probably leave the plotting out entirely; it's often easier for the user to do their own thing.

**Why go to all this trouble?** Fair question. `striplog` lets you merge zones, make thickness or lithology histograms, make queries ("show me sandstone beds thicker than 2 m"), make 'flags', export LAS or CSV, and even do Markov chain sequence analysis. But even if it's not what you're looking for, maybe you can recycle some of the plotting code! Good luck.